# Balancing a panel data for regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], "city": ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def10', 'def10', 'ghk'] ,"year": [2008, 2009, 2010, 2008, 2010,2009], "value": [10,20,30,10,20,30]})
```

```
    id  city     year  value
0   1    abc    2008    10 
1   1    abc    2009    20
2   1    abc    2010    30
3   2   def10   2008    10
4   2   def10   2010    20
5   3   ghk     2009    30
```

I wanna create a balanced data such that:

```
    id  city     year  value
0   1    abc    2008    10 
1   1    abc    2009    20
2   1    abc    2010    30
3   2   def10   2008    10
4   2   def10   2009    NaN
5   2   def10   2010    20
6   3   ghk     2008    NaN
7   3   ghk     2009    30
8   3   ghk     2009    NaN
```

if I use the following code:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
balanced = (id.set_index('year',append=True).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index,range(df.year.min(),df.year.max()+1)],names=['frs_id','year'])).reset_index(level=1))
```

This gives me following error:

```
cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot the table and stack `year` without drop NaN values:

```
>>> df.pivot(["id", "city"], "year", "value") \
      .stack(dropna=False) \
      .rename("value") \
      .reset_index()

   id   city  year  value
0   1    abc  2008   10.0
1   1    abc  2009   20.0
2   1    abc  2010   30.0
3   2  def10  2008   10.0
4   2  def10  2009    NaN
5   2  def10  2010   20.0
6   3    ghk  2008    NaN
7   3    ghk  2009   30.0
8   3    ghk  2010    NaN
```

**Edit**: case of duplicate entries

I slightly modified your original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1,2,2,3,3], "city": ['abc','abc','abc','def10','def10','ghk','ghk'], "year": [2008,2009,2010,2008,2010,2009,2009], "value": [10,20,30,10,20,30,40]})
```

```
>>> df
   id   city  year  value
0   1    abc  2008     10
1   1    abc  2009     20
2   1    abc  2010     30
3   2  def10  2008     10
4   2  def10  2010     20
5   3    ghk  2009     30  # The problem is here
6   3    ghk  2009     40  # same (id, city, year)
```

You need to take a decision. Do you want to keep the row 5 or 6 or apply a math function (mean, sum, ...). Imagine you want the mean for (3, ghk, 2009):

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index=["id", "city"], columns="year", values="value", aggfunc="mean") \
      .stack(dropna=False) \
      .rename("value") \
      .reset_index()

   id   city  year  value
0   1    abc  2008   10.0
1   1    abc  2009   20.0
2   1    abc  2010   30.0
3   2  def10  2008   10.0
4   2  def10  2009    NaN
5   2  def10  2010   20.0
6   3    ghk  2008    NaN
7   3    ghk  2009   35.0  # <- mean of (30, 40)
8   3    ghk  2010    NaN
```

Comment: I am getting this: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: It works on your sample `df`. Do you try on another data? (what is your version of pandas?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes, my version is  1.2.4.  yes I am working on another big data along with 20 plus columns

Answer (score 2):

You are close to the solution. You can amend your code slightly as follows:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(),range(df.year.min(),df.year.max()+1)],names=['id','year'])

df2 = df.set_index(['id', 'year']).reindex(idx).reset_index()

df2['city'] = df2.groupby('id')['city'].ffill().bfill()
```

Changes to your codes:

1. Create the MultiIndex by using unique values of `id` instead of from index
2. Set index on both `id` and `year` before reindex()
3. Fill-in the `NaN` values of column `city` by non-NaN entries of the same `id`

Result:

```
print(df2)

   id  year   city  value
0   1  2008    abc   10.0
1   1  2009    abc   20.0
2   1  2010    abc   30.0
3   2  2008  def10   10.0
4   2  2009  def10    NaN
5   2  2010  def10   20.0
6   3  2008    ghk    NaN
7   3  2009    ghk   30.0
8   3  2010    ghk    NaN
```

Optionally, you can re-arrange the column sequence, if you like:

```
df2.insert(2, 'year', df2.pop('year'))
```

```
print(df2)

   id   city  year  value
0   1    abc  2008   10.0
1   1    abc  2009   20.0
2   1    abc  2010   30.0
3   2  def10  2008   10.0
4   2  def10  2009    NaN
5   2  def10  2010   20.0
6   3    ghk  2008    NaN
7   3    ghk  2009   30.0
8   3    ghk  2010    NaN
```

### Edit

You can also do it using `stack()` and `unstack()` without using `reindex()`, as follows:

```
(df.set_index(['id', 'city', 'year'], append=True)
   .unstack()
   .groupby(level=[1, 2]).max()
   .stack(dropna=False)
).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id   city  year  value
0   1    abc  2008   10.0
1   1    abc  2009   20.0
2   1    abc  2010   30.0
3   2  def10  2008   10.0
4   2  def10  2009    NaN
5   2  def10  2010   20.0
6   3    ghk  2008    NaN
7   3    ghk  2009   30.0
8   3    ghk  2010    NaN
```